# error "fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree"?

Tags: git, flutter

I tried running the command 'flutter' in cmd. I am getting this error
please resolve it.

fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git  [...] -- [...]'

Comment: run `flutter upgrade` and it will set to correct git head

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error when I run `git subtree add` in a new git repo with no git commits.  It goes away after I create an initial commit:

```
touch README.md
git add README.md
git commit -m  "initial commit"
```

I'm not sure what flutter is, but I'm guessing that somewhere along the line it is also running into a repo with no commits in it.